# Codeigniter--add "active" css class to link, how to?

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

What's the quickest and easiest way to add the "active" class to a link, so it can be styled?  I'm developing an app in CI, and I'd like a quick easy way to do this automatically.

jQuery is an option too...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should really be using the CodeIgniter URI Class to do this instead of the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

$this->uri->uri_string()

```
if ( $this->uri->uri_string() == '/contact' )
```

^^ that is the preferred way to do things due to some complexities that can happen with codeigniter's routing features

Comment: Yea, I ended up using this method.

Comment: I had to use following for it to work
if ($this->uri->uri_string() == 'home')
//Remove the forward slash

Answer (score 6):

Depends on how you're outputting your link HTML.

If you're using the [URL Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) module, then you can call the `anchor()` function to create your links, and pass it an array of attributes as the third parameter, ie:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
echo anchor('url/path', 'Click here', array('class' => 'active'));
```

If you're just outputting the HTML manually in your templates/views, obviously you can just create the class attribute yourself in the HTML.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a lot of navigation items you can do it this way (very simplified)...

```
<ul>
<li<?= if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/contact' ): ?> id="active"<?php endif; ?>><a href="">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

You'll have to edit it for your needs...

If you don't have that many nav items an easier way is to give each page a body id and then use css to make it active.

```
<style type="text/css">
body#contact #contact-nav { font-weight:bold; }
</style>

<body id="contact">

<ul id="navigation">
    <li id="contact-nav"><a href="">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's awesome.  The first option worked (with a small adjustment)!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this way by creating helper with following

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
if ( ! function_exists('active_link'))
{
    function active_link($controller)
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();

        $class = $CI->router->fetch_class();
        return ($class == $controller) ? 'active' : '';
    }
}
```

then apply it in menu view

```
<li class="<?php echo active_link('services'); ?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>services">Services</a></li>
```

Comment: This question is 4 years old and your answer doesn't add benefit to the thread...

Comment: this is the simplest code block i have come across so far.. Thanks :)

Comment: @FahidMohammad  yes this is why i answered here although this question is very old.

Answer (score 1):

To adding active class (class=”active”) to a link , I’ve done it by doing this:
**In view**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs"> 
        <li id="button_home" class='<?php echo $home;?>'><?php echo anchor('pages/index','Home');?></li>
        <li id="button_about" class='<?php echo $about;?>'><?php echo anchor('pages/about','About')?></li> 
</ul>
```

**In controller**

```
$data['home']="active";
```

Maybe it's not your solution. but it works for me.